# Invalid Template Root error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to $watch an input element and as soon as the input element is set to a string "password" then I am toggling the class on element.children(1).But, when i try to do this i am getting an Invalid template root error..

Here is my code..

In index.html

```
 <div ng-app="app">
        <dumb-password></dumb-password>
 </div
```

In app.js,I am writing a directive

```
var myapp1 = angular.module('app', []);
myapp1.directive('dumbPassword', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'dumbpass.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch("model.input", function (value) {
                if (value === "password") {
                    element.children(1).toggleClass("alert-box alert");
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my dumbpass.html file

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model.input">
  <div>{{ model.input }}</div>
</div>
```

When i search the above error in angular js,It says,When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element,which is what i am doing in my case....I could't get the reason of occurence of the problem,and i am new to angular js.

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: Seems like its working here http://plnkr.co/edit/FSN6p58vdeMHEy6PiZCe?p=preview..could you validate it and reproduce an issue here ..